readBlock -> Expect block, but got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
I am getting an error while joining the channel by peer0 of an organisation. Below is the container log details. Any pointer on this error will be of great help
kubectl logs -n supplychain-net joinchannel-peer0-allchannel-r6lft --all-containers

Joining Channel allchannel
TlS Status is true
peer channel fetch 0 allchannel.block -o orderer1.supplychain-net:7050 -c allchannel --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/tls/orderer.crt
2024-11-11 13:00:13.898 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 009 [core] [Channel #1] Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2024-11-11 13:00:13.898 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 00a [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel created
2024-11-11 13:00:13.898 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 00b [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2024-11-11 13:00:13.898 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 00c [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel picks a new address "orderer1.supplychain-net:7050" to connect
2024-11-11 13:00:13.898 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 00d [core] pickfirstBalancer: UpdateSubConnState: 0xc00046e1a0, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2024-11-11 13:00:13.898 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 00e [core] [Channel #1] Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2024-11-11 13:00:13.901 UTC 001f DEBU [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake completed in 1.513094ms remoteaddress=10.244.1.213:7050
2024-11-11 13:00:13.901 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 00f [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2] Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2024-11-11 13:00:13.901 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 010 [core] pickfirstBalancer: UpdateSubConnState: 0xc00046e1a0, {READY <nil>}
2024-11-11 13:00:13.901 UTC [grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 011 [core] [Channel #1] Channel Connectivity change to READY
2024-11-11 13:00:13.901 UTC 0020 INFO [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2024-11-11 13:00:13.901 UTC 0021 DEBU [msp.identity] Sign -> Sign: plaintext: 0A9A090A1608051A0608DDFFC7B90622...933DB9B2652712080A021A0012021A00
2024-11-11 13:00:13.901 UTC 0022 DEBU [msp.identity] Sign -> Sign: digest: 6193885D35D12596D97BEF566BF9634BAAC21C2485D1FC6661C32D86EA2E1189
2024-11-11 13:00:13.902 UTC 0023 INFO [cli.common] readBlock -> Expect block, but got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
Error: can't read the block: &{NOT_FOUND}
join channel condition
peer channel join -b allchannel.block


Make sure that the allchannel channel is created in the orderer and that all the nodes have joined it

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
